# Bootstrap Modal-Dialog with D3 diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, c3.js

**First :**

I have a problem with a dynamic modal-dialog with a diagram in it.
The code is pretty easy:

https://jsfiddle.net/c2abnhja/1/

As you can see, no diagram is in the created div container. But if you resize your window, the diagram is drawn correctly with the correct size of the modal-dialog. [Also it doesn't matter if I trigger the resize event in manual : https://jsfiddle.net/ywaoec3d/1/ ]

**And in second:**

If I set a size to the modal dialog of bootstrap, like here:
https://jsfiddle.net/aqs5fhha/1/
the diagram never get the correct height of the modal-content... but the documentation of c3.js says :

```
size.height

The desired height of the chart element.

If this option is not specified, the height of the chart will be
calculated by the size of the parent element it's appended to.
```

Any idea why the diagram is not drawn correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix your problem using this :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#diagramAppend',
        data: {
            x: 'x',
            columns: [
                ['x', 30, 50, 100, 230, 300, 310],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 130, 300, 200, 300, 250, 450]
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

Basically what is happening is that you try to generate your graph on a `div` with 0 `width`. Waiting the event `shown.bs.modal` allow you to have a `width` at this point.

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywaoec3d/2/)